# Como puxar uma ForeignKey do models no django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Olá estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação é estou com um problema, se alguém souber como resolver.
Eu criei os seguintes Models:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
email = models.EmailField(null=False)
senha = models.CharField('Senha',max_length=100, null=True)
celular = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False)
data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='clients_photos', null= True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.nome 

class Dieta(models.Model):
    nome = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    periodo1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    refeicao1 = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    periodo2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    refeicao2 = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Dieta'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nome)
```

Agora eu quero puxar essa Dieta para ser exibida no html e não estou conseguindo acessar seus atributos, segue classe view dessa função:

```py
def dieta(request):  
    dieta = Dieta.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'dieta.html', {'dieta' : dieta})
```

Comment: Tenha em atenção que está a buscar todos os registos de dieta da base de dados e não apenas um.
Como é que está a aceder à variável dieta no template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, a sua variável `dieta` é uma queryset que retorna todas as dietas cadastradas no seu banco de dados. Caso você queira pegar só uma dieta, seria o caso de passar algum parâmetro no seu método, algo como:

```py
def dieta(request, id):
    try:
        dieta = Dieta.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # dispara alguma exceção
```

**OU**

Caso você queira exibir todas as dietas no template, a sua view continua como está, só trocaria o nome da variável de `dieta` para `dietas` e no template você faria algo como:

```
{% for dieta in dietas %}
   {{ dieta.nome }}
{% endfor %}
```

Dentro da iteração você tem acesso aos atributos da sua classe.

Espero ter ajudado.